# Sentence Transitions

Tags: transitions

> Dogs use their excellent sense of smell to detect friends and foe around them. **Nevertheless,** bats rely on their incredible ears to navigate the world using echolocation.

A. NO CHANGE

B. In the same way,

C. On the other hand,

D. Otherwise,

I picked C because I thought it was contrast. Correct Answer is B. Is the question wrong because we might require bit more context? Please explain answer choice B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have my sympathy. C contrasts what bats do with what dogs do. That seems right because smell and hearing are different senses. The only sense (sorry!) in which what dogs do and what bats do are "in the same way" is that both animals use their senses to understand what is going on around them. How else are they to do that? Telepathy?

B is grammatically correct, but a silly thing to say.